# Linux sar command to print header in the first line ONLY

Tags: linux

In RHEL Linux, if I read historic data from saXX file, it prints the header (e.g. %user     %nice   %system ) after every 45th line.  Whether we can change this behavior ? (like in hp-ux, description header gets printed one time only - it does not repeat) .

Comment: How about `grep -v '%'`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
sar | cat
```

I'm not entirely sure why, but the headers after the first one aren't actually included in stdout, stderr, etc, so piping to cat removes them and the extra spaces generated before them.